# UnixODBC reads ASCII?ANSI although It is compiled with iconv enabled

Tags: 16.04, php, oracle, odbc

I have been searching for this issue for quite a while, please do not be quick to give me similar questions, here is the issue:

1. I installed and configured unixodbc on ubuntu, connected it to
   oracle and connection works
2. I installed and configured php-odbc,
   also works with the unixodbc and connects to oracle
3. The issue is
   that it retrieves data in ASCII and I cannot find any proper way to
   force it to use utf8.

Comment: What do you use to retrieve data and what points you to the conclusion that it is ASCII?

Comment: I use odbc_fetch_array after odbc_exec, and two indicators show that it is ascii, ????? instead of garbled characters (so it is not a simple utf8 to another encoding method that I can use iconv) and I did mb_detect_encoding

Comment: Could you make sure of the encoding on the server side and on the client side?  It is then possible to use `odbc_exec($this->link, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET=UTF-8")`

Comment: Does not execute